# Virtual keyboard does not appear

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

When my mobile application I am doing a load, I call the form that handles the camera to take a picture of a receipt. Upon returning to the upload form, if I select an edit, the virtual keyboard does not appear.

That problem can be having? Is there a way to force this keyboard appears?

Comment: set Focus on EditText or TextView field

Comment: I tried without solving the problem. It focuses on the edit, but no longer appears the cursor to write.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
   /**
     * This method used to hide soft keyboard.
     */
    public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method used to show soft keyboard.
     */
    public void showSoftKeyboard() {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```